# how to use rank on rows return from Left Outer join on inner select query in oracle?

Tags: oracle, left-join, rank

Hi All I have below 3 tables

```
 Table1
 -------
 EMP001

 table2: Emp     Date1     Date2
 ----------------------------------
        EMP001  01/01/12  12/31/12
        EMP001  01/01/13  12/31/13
        EMP001  01/01/14  12/31/14

table3: Emp     Date1      Date2
-----------------------------------
       EMP001   01/01/12  12/31/15
       EMP001   01/01/13  12/31/15
```

Here table3 has overlapping span dates which is a bad data.

when i join

```
 select * from
 table1 left outer join table2 
 on table1.emp = table2.emp
 left outer join table3
 on table1.emp = table3.emp
 and table2.date1 between table3.date1 and table3.date2
```

Above query returns 4 rows as table3 has overlapping spans.

```
 EMP     Table2.Date1   Table2.Date2      Table3.Date1    Table3.Date2
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 EMP001  01/01/12        12/31/12         01/01/12       12/31/15
 EMP001  01/01/13        12/31/13         01/01/12       12/31/15
 EMP001  01/01/13        12/31/13         01/01/13       12/31/15
 EMP001  01/01/14        12/31/14
```

Here I need only one row for each row of table2. From table3 I need data as max(date1) and table2.date1 between table3.date1 and table3.date1

I can't join table 3 as below as costs huge for performance.

```
 select * from
 table1
 left outer join table2
 on table2.emp = table2.emp
 left outer join
 (select table2.date1 as t2date1, table3.*, rom_number() over (partition by table3.emp, table2.date1) as Rank
 from table3,table2
 where table2.emp = table3.emp
 and table2.date1 between table3.date1 and table3.date2) tbl3
 on table1.emp = tbl3.emp
 and table2.date1 = tbl3.t2date1
```

Is there a way to avoid 2 tables join inside inner select query and get the single row for table2 dates.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I lost the train of thought about two-thirds of the way into your explanation (maybe that is not your fault), but: It seems you are asking for help on writing code to work around bad data. That is both difficult and dangerous; data may be wrong in unexpected ways, and you will get incorrect outcomes and **nobody will even know that, ever**. The proper solution is to fix the data. If that is not possible (which is very rarely true, most often it is just a hurdle raised by inept business people), create a view from your table 3, in which you fix data as best possible, and use it in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Sorry for syntax errors if any.
Place primary key fields of table1 and table2 instead of `table1.rowid, table2.rowid`:

```
select
  emp, t2_date1, t2_date2, t3_date1
from (
    select
      table1.emp,
      table2.Date1 as t2_date1,
      table2.Date2 as t2_date2,
      table3.Date1 as t3_date1,
      row_number() over (partition by table1.rowid, table2.rowid order by t3.date1 desc) as rn
    from
     table1
     left outer join table2
     on table1.emp = table2.emp
     left outer join table3
     on table1.emp = table3.emp
     and table2.date1 between table3.date1 and table3.date2
)
where rn = 1
;
```